# REGEXMATCH Count Zero If None

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to count all cells that contain this exact string somewhere in the cell   "(w)"
The formula below shows 1 when there are none found
How can I make it show 0 if none are found?

```
COUNTA(FILTER(D2:D55, REGEXMATCH(D2:D55, "(w)")))
```

Comment: try `"\(w\)"` and see what happen

Comment: Adding the slashes still counts 1 when there are none

Comment: Hmmm... ok, what may be happening than is that it is counting 1 occurrence for the whole column. I would then create an extra column that would have the result of `REGEXMATCH` as 1 / 0 and the count based on that column.